# customize the mat-calendar, remove month label

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to remove the month label from angular material mat-calendar.
Here is the stackblitz link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-mviy6e?file=styles.scss

```
  <mat-calendar [dateClass]="dateClass()" [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)"></mat-calendar>


onSelect(event){
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedDate = event;
  }

  dateClass() {
    return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
      const highlightDate = this.datesToHighlight
        .map(strDate => new Date(strDate))
        .some(d => d.getDate() === date.getDate() && d.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && d.getFullYear() === date.getFullYear());

      return highlightDate ? 'special-date' : '';
    };
```

}

For css:-

```
.mat-calendar-body-label{
   display: none;
  }
```

If i use above css code then, it move the calendar dates from left to right and make calendar distorted.

if I use this:-

```
.mat-calendar-body-label{
  opacity: 0;
  }
```

then it will leave empty row if there is no date

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to:

```
.mat-calendar-body-label{
     opacity: 0;
}
```

Add the following to get rid of the extra space when the first of the month starts on the first column:

```
.mat-calendar-body-label[colspan="7"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I have borders so it removed borders

Comment: here ois the stackblitz 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-mviy6e?file=styles.scss

Comment: So you want empty boxes where the month once was?

Comment: Ok, think I understand now. Continue using opacity: 0; to just hide the month and maintain the outer border with the addition of the [colspan="7"] rule. That should do the trick. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Due to encapsulation you need to use shadow piercing to get at the style of the calendar, so use the ng-deep selector.

```
::ng-deep .mat-calendar-body-label{
   display: none;
  }
```

Comment: That will still cause the dates to shift over. Additionally, you don't need ng-deep if this rule is set at the parent level.

Comment: I did encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

Comment: Use visibility: hidden; instead of display: none

.mat-calendar-body-label {
     visibility: hidden;
}

Answer (score 0):

I used both below styles as suggested above

```css
/deep/ .mat-calendar-body-label {
    visibility: hidden;
}
/deep/ .mat-calendar-body-label[colspan="7"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use first css to remove the month label and make the calendar height to adjust auto. Add to `styles.css` for global access.

```css
.mat-calendar-body-label {
  display: none !important;
}
.mat-datepicker-content .mat-calendar {
  height: auto !important;
}
```